# Lifespan of memory card when only small data are written

Tags: sd-card, lifespan

Being Surface user, I have to rely on SD cards as my primary data storage. Most of big files will be stored long term and "read only", but some folders I will use as cache.

So lets say, if 80% of data will be permanently stored, and 20% will be rewriten every day, should I expect the same wear-out of the card as I would rewrite whole (100%) of the card.

In other words, the "thing" which has limited lifespan is the "controler" who organize the data, or the "data cells" itself ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All kinds of flash memory have limited number of writes. It's due to physical wear of memory cells when they're being written to.

If the controller is built well, the worn-out cells will either be silently remapped to good spares without you noticing, or they will become read-only when the controller runs out of spares. (I'm not sure if SD cards have spares at all, but eg. SSD drives do.)

If the controller is built to be cheap or something fails in an unexpected way, anything can happen, including entire SD card becoming immediately inaccessible.

I would never consider an SD card as a reliable storage for anything due to their fragility and relatively high failure rates. If you have to, make sure your backups are working and are set to be made frequently enough.

Answer (score 2):

I would never **expect** any given life-span of an SD card [nor USB flash].

These things are stunningly fragile - one mis-write & it will permanently lock; one accidental disconnect & the entire thing is toast.
If you use them read only, then you do get uneven wear which will lead to data loss eventually, even if you get over the first two hurdles.

I used to get through literally thousands of these things for work. The task I had involved *write once, read many* operations, so we would quite quickly run the cards to destruction; but it does give you a good feel for these things as an average. Some would run a couple of years or more with tolerable [if far from perfect] error rates, some would die in three days. As none of this data was unique, we simply didn't care so long as they limped along. This is emphatically not the same as if they were carrying vital data.

Once you see for yourself the sheer scale of "sudden death" in SD cards [or read the myriad sad & sorry tales of permanently lost data we see on here every week] then you would no longer trust one as far as you can spit it.

It is vital that you do not keep any data on only one card. If you must use cards & nothing else, then you should copy all data to at least three of them, always, every time, no skips, no regrets.

Comment: Related: [MicroSD card performance deteriorates after long-term read-only usage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/538328/34837)

Comment: We did actually in later years use playback devices which would first read the card into faster, more robust, memory in the device, then playback from that. The lifespan of the devices was then around 2 - 5 years & the cards [already badly worn from the previous incarnation] tended to limp along for longer after that. These were mass-deployed in their thousands, retail devices where no-one really cared if everything was perfect 24/7. We'd just go out & check/swap/discard every month or so.

Answer (score 1):

> should I expect the same wear-out of the card as I would rewrite whole (100%) of the card.

As wear time does not have an exactly defined range and it depends on several factors - from which usage pattern is not the main one - I wouldn't expect big difference in your case.